# Portable device to show powerpoint and video content that is read only and offline

Tags: laptop, tablet

I need to purchase around 10 tablets or laptops to enable very technically challenged users to open powerpoint presentations and videos that I copy manually onto the device.

The following restrictions will apply to the device
- no network connectivity allowed
- no copying of content to or from the device via hardware ports
Only I as sysadmin will be able to unlock those restrictions with the device physically with me.

The device needs to be able to connect to a variety of old and new projectors using HDMI or VGA.
The device needs a screen that the presenter can see

I am currently considering: 
- Android device that has VGA and HDMI ports or adapters for them
- iPad with VGA and HDMI port adapters
- windows laptops running Windows enterprise (10 licenses) so I can use Microsoft Applocker to lock down the entire laptop so only Powerpoint and VLC player can be used

Firstly what would you recommend from the above options - cost is sensitive here.

Second are there any better options I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to argue that the [Dell Latitude E6430 Laptop](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834299263&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Notebooks-_-N82E16834299263&gclid=CjwKEAjwmMS-BRCm5dn51JLbp1wSJACc61tFcVHEnhCJPNlz54xkykjkBrEksXtXjByx_922bnBVhhoCFgHw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) as refurbished by Newegg represents the *perfect* solution to your problem.

First and foremost, this machine meets all of your hardware requirements - it has HDMI and VGA outs, and it has the graphical horsepower and resolution to cleanly and clearly display these presentations on both screens simultaneously.

The real bonus here is that it comes with Windows 7 Professional, which is is a very special OS for your purposes. Unlike earlier and later versions of Windows, Windows 7 Pro can freely install the Windows XP Mode, which is functionally a VM of Windows XP. With this VM set up and [duplicated as many times as you need](http://xpmore.codeplex.com/), you can mirror your display to the projector and have their presentation run in a full-screen VM window, which can be configured to prevent them from accessing any of the hardware ports or networking ports. It is possible to set it up so that only technical users would know how to get out of the virtual machine's window. It's also a fairly cheap and powerful solution, so that's nice.